# How can I find out which third-party sites a webservice (in this case: Spritzlet) is using?

Tags: tracking, cookies, traffic

I'm comparing the current incarnations of various "Spritz" applications, like the **official [Spritzlet](http://sdk.spritzinc.com/js/1.2/bookmarklet/index.html)**, and the unofficial [Squirt](https://www.squirt.io/install.html), [OpenSpritz](https://github.com/Miserlou/OpenSpritz/), [Readline](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/readline/hjbkmfadmomgaokjodomncmbgmmodona?hl=en), etc. -- The official **[Spritzlet](http://sdk.spritzinc.com/js/1.2/bookmarklet/index.html)** is a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) which comes with the ***requirement*** of allowing **third-party cookies**, presumably for personalized ad purposes.

I'd like to use Google's Chromium (Chrome) browser to test **[Spritzlet](http://sdk.spritzinc.com/js/1.2/bookmarklet/index.html)**, which allows the user to set **site/domain specific exceptions** (whitelist or blacklist, clear-on-exit) for **cookies** and site-data:

```
chrome://settings/content

chrome://settings/contentExceptions#cookies
```

I imagine that [Spritz](http://www.spritzinc.com)'s ad sites might be constantly changing and that we're talking about a "moving target". Be that as it may,

- *How* can I find out **which third-party sites** **[Spritzlet](http://sdk.spritzinc.com/js/1.2/bookmarklet/index.html)** is using?
- .. browser in-built traffic monitoring?
- .. extensions/addons?
- .. just reading directly from the user-visible code?

A first quick glance at https://sdk.spritzinc.com/js/1.2/bookmarklet/js/SpritzletOuter.js did not offer me any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Hey nutty about natty,

I'm the front-end developer that worked on the Spritzlet. First off, thanks for the interest in Spritz! Just so you know, you're always free to send any other questions or suggested improvements to support@spritzinc.com.

While I can't address your main question, I can say that the Spritzlet is ad free. Our requirement for allowing third-party cookies is for two reasons: the Spritzlet loads a number of external files onto the current page from our domain (sdk.spritzinc.com), which makes us a third-party to that page because our files don't originate from that page's domain. Additionally, we make use of HTML5 localStorage, which browsers sometimes treat similarly in settings related with cookies (Safari comes to mind in this case). The Spritzlet does do usage and analytics tracking via Google Analytics, but definitely nothing ad related.

Note that the above only applies to the Spritzlet, I can't speak for other sites/technologies.