# Can Firefox tell me which third-party cookies are blocked for a given page?

Tags: firefox, cookies

I would like to create exceptions for select third-party cookies. But, I don't know what domains the third-party cookies come from (yet). Typically this is for logins to white-labelled support sites e.g. those managed by Zendesk.

Is there any way to see what third-party cookies are being blocked on a given page?

Comment: similar to https://superuser.com/questions/775425/how-can-i-find-out-which-third-party-sites-a-webservice-in-this-case-spritzlet but firefox not chrome, and focused on cookies rather than saas/bookmarklet that uses cookies

Comment: mayyyyyybe a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1013829/how-to-know-which-cookies-are-associated-to-a-specific-website ? the answer there works in theory but seems... tedious

Answer (score 0):

If you visit a page in Firefox, on the left side of the address bar you find a shield icon. Clicking on that you can check what is blocked under which category (i.e. third-party cookies, different kind of trackers etc.).

Find out more in [this article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/content-blocking#w_how-to-detect-when-content-blocking-is-on).

(You cannot tell, however, for an already saved third-party cookie, which site it originates from.)